# Returning multiple values from a loop w/o getting the "None"

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

Is there any way to return multiple results without having to create a blank tuple, add each iteration to it, and return the tuple?

I just want to get rid of the implicitly returned `None` at the end of loop.

```
from random import randint

class Lotto(object):
    def fir_num(self):
        print("First prize:")
        num = randint(000000, 999999)
        return "%06d" % num           #no problem for single value

    def sec_num(self):
        print("Second prizes:")
        i = 0
        while i <= 5:
            i += 1
            num = randint(000000, 999999)
            print("%06d" % num)       #if uses "return", the function returns only one result

L = Lotto()
print(L.fir_num())
print(L.sec_num())
```

Comment: You might consider a `yield` statement to return an iterable. I don't think that's exactly the answer you're looking for, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only return once from a function. So the best would be to collect your result in a list and return the list:

```
from random import randint

def sec_num(count=5):
    return [randint(0, 999999) for _ in range(count)]

for num in sec_num():
    print("%06d" % num)
```

Output:

```
710690
816475
087483
572131
292748
```

Looks like you don't access `self`. Therefore, you don't need a class for the case you show in your example. Going with simple function seems preferable here.

If you have many second prices, say a million or so, you can make your function more efficient using `yield`. This would turn your function into a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/functional.html#generators). This is a whole new concept to understand and ne need for case but worthwhile to explore when you get deeper into Python.

Answer (score 2):

You could try modifying your `sec_num()` function to use following generator approach.

```
from random import randint

class Lotto(object):
    def sec_num(self):
        print("Second prizes:")
        i = 0
        while i <= 5:
            i += 1
            num = randint(000000, 999999)
            yield("%06d" % num)

L = Lotto()
for g in L.sec_num():
     print(g)
```

`yield` acts like `return`, but it turns the function into a generator. If you just print `L.sec_num()`, you'll see a generator object. This is an iterable so you can step through it as above to get the values it contains.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good place to use `yield` - you use it just like `return`, but instead of the function returning that one value and stopping, it gives back multiple results in turn as the caller iterates over them. It would look like this:

```
class Lotto:
    def sec_num(self):
        print("Second prizes:")
        i = 0
        while i <= 5:
            i += 1
            num = randint(000000, 999999)
            yield "%06d" % num

L = Lotto()
for num in L.sec_num():
    print(num)
```

This is somewhat like building a list in the function, except it lets `sec_num` focus on its job rather than the administrative logic of building the list; also, it can be more efficient in some circumstances (especially combined with the stdlib `itertools` module), since each new result is only generated as the *caller* wants it rather than it having to wait for all of them. If you do want all of them in a list, you can still do this: `print(list(L.sec_num()))` .

Answer (score 1):

The right solution in this case is to return a List `[32372,43483,54579..]` or a dictionary with structure like `{"first":38179,"second":36368..}` You can have varying number of results each time.